# How to release the char array after return it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

Guy, I confused how to release the object **pResult** in the below code snippet

```
inline char* UnicodeToAnsi(const wchar_t* szStr, int& nLen)
    {
        nLen = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, szStr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (nLen == 0)
            return NULL;

        char* pResult = new char[nLen];
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, szStr, -1, pResult, nLen, NULL, NULL);

        return pResult;
    }
```

I call it at:

```
string region_str(UnicodeToAnsi(regionValue, region_str_len));
```

In the C++ if we create a object by new, I must to release it manually, but in this case, I must return the value. If I release it, I can't use it anymore.

Do I need to release the **pResult**? if yes, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: The caller has to know to call `delete[]` on the returned pointer. That is one of the reasons this is a poor design.

Comment: This would be  considerably more robust to manufacture and return a `std::string`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, maybe this is the only way to do that, this is indeed a bad design, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** call `delete []` on the pointer returned by `UnicodeToAnsi()`.

Otherwise, you'll have a memory leak.

---

For example:

```
char* ansi_str = UnicodeToAnsi(regionValue, region_str_len);
string region_str(ansi_str);
delete [] ansi_str;
```

However, a proper C++ solution would be to make `UnicodeToAnsi()` return an `std::string` and use that:

```
string region_str = UnicodeToAnsi(regionValue, region_str_len);
```